# Which is the right response for the question "Did you do your homework?"

Tags: past-tense

I am trying to refresh my grammar and I want to remember what was the right past tense for this question

> Did you do your homework?
>
> 1. Yes I did it
> 2. Yes I have done it
> 3. Yes I had done it

Which is correct and when should I use others ?

Answer (score 1):

“Yes, I did it” is the right answer to “Did you do your homework?”. But it would be more likely for the question to be “Have you done your homework?”, to which the answer is “Yes, I have done it” (or in speech, nearly always “Yes, I’ve done it”).

The difference is that “Did you do your homework?” is asking about the past —— did you, at some time in the past, do your homework? “Have you done your homework?” is asking about the present situation — are you, right now, in a state of having done your homework?

Comment: I think "Did you do your homework?" would be idiomatic in American English, but I'll leave it to the Americans to suggest what the natural reply would be.

Answer (score 1):

Both

> Yes I did it

and

> Yes I have done it

are correct and good responses to the question. It would be normal to reflect the form of the question, so if asked "Did you do your homework?" you would normally say "Yes, I did it." If asked "Have you done your homework?" (which means the same thing) you would answer "Yes, I have done it."

"Yes I had done it" is pluperfect tense and incorrect here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do your homework?

Yes I did.

---

Have you done your homework?

Yes I have.